# How to format a TeX expression while rendering in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, ckeditor

I am having a TeX expression: `\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)`

The html code is:

```
<span class="math-tex">\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>
```

The expression should be displayed as:

[image]

How is it possible? Should I add any `Javascript` code?

Comment: You need to add Mathjax --- http://www.mathjax.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is include it like an image with url parameter as a tex equation:

```
<img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?x&space;=&space;{-b&space;\pm&space;\sqrt{b^2-4ac}&space;\over&space;2a}" title="x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}" />
```

If you have many formulas and going to manipulate them constantly -- you need append the plugin to the editor. Yes, it going to be JS, and yes, it might be http://www.mathjax.org/